# phpMyAdmin shows white page with no error

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, freebsd

Im using FreeBSD with nginx, php & mysql.
Everything fine until i decided to upgrade my php to 5.6.
Then i installed phpMyAdmin from ports. 
My problem is phpMyAdmin won't show up. It displays white screen with no error, even i set error to be displayed in php.ini.
Websites & mysql is running well. I can even echoed out something in index.php (phpmyadmin folder).
Here is my config.inc.php setting:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '*******';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '*******';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Comment: Did you check your log files for errors?

Comment: thanks, i got this error in my httpd-error.log:
    *1801 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined   function mb_detect_encoding() in /usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin/libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc on line 177"

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the `php-mbstring` package in your compile

Comment: yeap. managed to get its running now. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure mbstring is installed and loaded in php.ini